# Deal with Birtish summer time

Tags: python, pytz

I have a date string `18 May 14:30` which corresponds to the British summertime (`WEST` or `UTC+1`). I would like to convert it to central Euopean (summer)time.

Here is my code

```
# from datetime import datetime
# from pytz import timezone

d = '18 May 14:30'
# Attempt 1
dd=datetime.strptime(d, '%d %b %H:%M').replace(year=datetime.now().year, tzinfo=timezone('WET'))
dd.astimezone(timezone('CET'))
# datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 18, 16, 30, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'CET' CEST+2:00:00 DST>)
# It should be 15:30, not 16:30

# Attempt 2
dd=datetime.strptime(d, '%d %b %H:%M').replace(year=datetime.now().year, tzinfo=timezone('WET'))
# Same result as above

# Attempt 3
dd=datetime.strptime(d, '%d %b %H:%M').replace(year=datetime.now().year, tzinfo=timezone('Etc/GMT-1'))
dd.astimezone(timezone('CET'))
# datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 18, 15, 30, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'CET' CEST+2:00:00 DST>)
# This works
```

So my problem in the third attempt I had to manually specify `GMT-1` whereas `CET` *automatically* transforms to `CEST`. I hoped this would work identically for `WET` (to `WEST`).

Besides, what also confuses me is the fact that according to Wiki British summertime should be `UTC +1` but I had to set `GMT-1` (as `GMT+1` returns `18:30`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case it interests someone, I did manage to find a workaround

```
dd=datetime.strptime(d, '%d %b %H:%M').replace(year=datetime.now().year)
timezone('WET').localize(dd).astimezone(timezone('CET'))
# datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 18, 15, 30, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'CET' CEST+2:00:00 DST>)
# Correct result without having to specify the shift

# Let's check with another date (non-summertime)
d = '18 Jan 14:30'
dd=datetime.strptime(d, '%d %b %H:%M').replace(year=datetime.now().year)
timezone('WET').localize(dd).astimezone(timezone('CET'))
# datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 18, 15, 30, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'CET' CET+1:00:00 STD>)
# Yay!
```

It's not very elegant but at least it does the job.